# Show and Hide Divs at certain periods of the day with Javascript (Refresh)

Tags: javascript

I have 4 different containers (DIVs). Each with a content relevant to a certain time period of the day. **This is not a webpage that will reload**. I have successfully  managed to have those DIVSs hide and show according to the right times. However, that only happens on page load.

This page will be open on a screen all day on a computer with no keyboard no mouse.

I hate to have the page every 30 minutes to have this happen.

Does anybody have a solution for this? Thanks for the help.

(Not sure why the code is not working here. I have got it working on my test page... Sorry)

```js
var myMenu1 = document.getElementById('rt-showcase3');
var myMenu2 = document.getElementById('rt-showcase3a');
var myMenu3 = document.getElementById('rt-showcase3b');
var myMenu4 = document.getElementById('rt-showcase3c');
var myMenu5 = document.getElementById('rt-showcase3d');

myMenu2.hide();
myMenu3.hide();
myMenu4.hide();
myMenu5.hide();

var d = new Date();
if (d.getHours() >= 6 && d.getHours() <= 10) {
  myMenu1.hide();
  myMenu2.show();
} else if (d.getHours() >= 10 && d.getHours() <= 14) {
  myMenu1.hide();
  myMenu2.hide();
  myMenu3.show();
} else if (d.getHours() >= 14 && d.getHours() <= 23) {
  myMenu1.hide();
  myMenu2.hide();
  myMenu3.hide();
  myMenu4.show();

} else {
  myMenu1.show();
  myMenu2.hide();
  myMenu3.hide();
  myMenu4.hide();
}
```

```css
.time {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
  min-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px #ddd;
  color: #bbb;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="rt-showcase3" class="time">SLEEP</div>
  <div id="rt-showcase3a" class="time">MORNING</div>
  <div id="rt-showcase3b" class="time">NOON</div>
  <div id="rt-showcase3c" class="time">AFTERNOON</div>
  <div id="rt-showcase3d" class="time">EVENING</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I had the same issue on a project of mine. I managed to have the page with an empty div and to run an ajax call every 30 minutes with jquery load() and setTimeout() to load the content without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Initially, I misunderstood the question as div not hiding and showing.
Updated the JS fiddle link.

```
var myMenu1 = document.getElementById('rt-showcase3');
var myMenu2 = document.getElementById('rt-showcase3a');
var myMenu3 = document.getElementById('rt-showcase3b');
var myMenu4 = document.getElementById('rt-showcase3c');
var myMenu5 = document.getElementById('rt-showcase3d');

myMenu2.style.display = 'none';
myMenu3.style.display = 'none';
myMenu4.style.display = 'none';
myMenu5.style.display = 'none';

(function update(){
var d = new Date();
if (d.getHours() >= 6 && d.getHours() <= 10) {
  myMenu1.style.display = 'none';
  myMenu2.style.display = 'block';
} else if (d.getHours() >= 10 && d.getHours() <= 14) {
  myMenu1.style.display = 'none';
  myMenu2.style.display = 'none';
  myMenu3.style.display = 'block';
} else if (d.getHours() >= 14 && d.getHours() <= 23) {
  myMenu1.style.display = 'none';
  myMenu2.style.display = 'none';
  myMenu3.style.display = 'none';
  myMenu4.style.display = 'block';

} else {
  myMenu1.style.display = 'block';
  myMenu2.style.display = 'none';
  myMenu3.style.display = 'none';
  myMenu4.style.display = 'none';
}
})();
var updateTimeout = 60 * 1000;//1 minute
setInterval(update,updateTimeout);
```

Jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/j9hjob63/1/

Use setInterval

Comment: where is this different from OP's  question?

Comment: myMenu2.hide() and myMenu2.show() is not any function. Use myMenu1.style.display = 'none' and  myMenu2.style.display = 'block'.

Comment: He is including jquery which defines show() and hide() as functions.  His code is correct.

Comment: they both are functions and OP has declared that on page load the code works fine!

Comment: OP is speaking about 30 minutes not 1 minute

Answer (score 0):

It only happens on refresh since function is only executed when the page loads. You can solve this by using setInterval()

```
setInterval(function(){
 //Check and hide divs
}, intervalTime)
```

Where interval time is the time in milliseconds

Comment: you are not explaining what OP is supposed to do with this code. Please elaborate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will reload the page every 60 minutes and will round the first execution so that if you open the page at 08:37 it will reload the first time at 09:00.

You can adapt it to 30 minutes if you need. If you don't want to have the page reloaded you need to move the div content to external files and have them loaded with ajax.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    setTimeout( function(){
        location.reload();
    },10000)
},3600000 - ((new Date) % 3600000));
```

The trick is on the last part of the function that will calculate the time diff for the first hour.

Answer (score -1):

You can run a check every 5 seconds

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  /// hide and show divs
}, 5000);
```

So you can call your function in there.

Comment: OP is talking about a 30 minutes interval not 5 seconds. Also he has the issue he doesn't want to refresh the page but this is what it's code does now.

Comment: this does not refresh the page.

Comment: this does nothing actually: neither refreshing nor anything else... Will you elaborate your idea?

Comment: inside the function they can place their code to hide and show divs accordingly

Comment: Thanks so much guys for your help and prompt responses. Just to clarify a bit, I don't mind checking for interval every 15 minutes and even every 5 minutes. But what I don't want is to refresh the entire page periodically. I have other content on the page that needs to remain unrefreshed. Think of it like a 18 hours video that may be re-winded back if the page is refreshed... So, I just want to have those Divs swap every period... I am now using the last code that user3785351 posted and I will test it. I will let you know if it works.

Comment: Yeah... it looks like it is not swapping when time comes... I have tested twice on two different browsers. The divs didn't swap the previous one remained there until I refreshed...

Comment: use alert for testing. does the interval work properly?

Comment: The interval is working cause when I refresh it changes. It just doesn't refresh automatically... I had to reload.